# ScrollView with a match_parent height view inside

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's start with screenshots I have prepare for this question

[image: 1] [image]

in this layout, maybe that big banner was not exists, so it's hide as you see in the other picture.
a part of this layout contains a text, so I want to scroll hole contents together but I want height of the background under text fills my screen and don't effect on the scroll, so scroll must active when the text was too long or banner's height was bigger.

this is my layout codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".NewsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_news">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bigPicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/tama_logo" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/largeIcon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"

                android:id="@+id/messageBody"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/largeIcon"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/largeIcon">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    style="@style/news_activity_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body"
                    style="@style/news_activity_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="1369/12/25 22:45:32"
            android:textColor="#aaa"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@+id/largeIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/messageBody"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

this picture would explane what I expect, sorry for my bad english :(

[image]

Comment: Off the top of my head, have you tried setting the ScrollView instead of the RelativeLayout to fillViewport="true" and setting the RelativeLayout to height "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"? I may be misunderstanding which view you are trying to alter

Comment: @ChadSchultz I use fillViewport="true" in scrollview and set RelativeLayout to height "match_parent, but still same result. i need that relativelayout, fill the parrent vertically but don't effect on the scrolling

Comment: @ChadSchultz can I use a framelayout under scrollview and set width of that as width of my realativelayout programmatically? is that OK ?

Answer (score 2):

Check below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bigPicture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tama_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    style="@style/news_activity_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body"
                    style="@style/news_activity_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2" />


            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/largeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/largeIcon"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="1369/12/25 22:45:32"
                    android:textColor="#aaa"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.